# modal data is not displaying jqgrid

Tags: model-view-controller, jqgrid

I need bind the `json` data to `jqGridView` but its displaying the data like below,

```
[{"name":"anita","qualification":"B.tech","login_id":null,"state":null},
{"name":"kavitha","qualification":"B.tech","login_id":null,"state":null},
{"name":"mounika","qualification":"B.tech","login_id":null,"state":null},
{"name":"radha","qualification":"M.tech","login_id":null,"state":null},
{"name":"JILLU","qualification":"B.tech","login_id":null,"state":null},
{"name":"divya","qualification":"MBA","login_id":null,"state":null},
{"name":"priya","qualification":"B.tech","login_id":null,"state":"andhra pradesh "},
{"name":"dhanwin","qualification":"B tech","login_id":null,"state":"karnataka      "},
{"name":"dhanwin","qualification":"B tech","login_id":null,"state":"karnataka      "},
{"name":"rakesh","qualification":"B tech","login_id":null,"state":"telagana       "},
{"name":"rathode","qualification":"MBA","login_id":"rathode123","state":"karnataka      "},
{"name":"erw","qualification":"","login_id":"","state":"               "},
{"name":"","qualification":"","login_id":null,"state":"               "},
{"name":"asdfsd","qualification":"fdg","login_id":null,"state":"hgjh           "},
{"name":"saddfs","qualification":"sdfsg","login_id":null,"state":"gfhg           "},
{"name":"saddfs","qualification":"sdfsg","login_id":null,"state":"gfhg           "},
{"name":"saddfs","qualification":"sdfsg","login_id":null,"state":"gfhg           "},
{"name":"saddfs","qualification":"sdfsg","login_id":null,"state":"gfhg           "},
{"name":"saddfs","qualification":"sdfsg","login_id":null,"state":"gfhg           "},
{"name":"","qualification":"","login_id":null,"state":"               "},
{"name":"","qualification":"","login_id":null,"state":"               "},
{"name":"","qualification":"","login_id":null,"state":"               "},
{"name":"dfgdf","qualification":"dfgd","login_id":null,"state":"fdhg           "},
{"name":"","qualification":"","login_id":null,"state":"               "},
{"name":"sdaf","qualification":"fdg","login_id":null,"state":"dfgsdfgffffffff"},
{"name":"ty","qualification":"gfhgf","login_id":null,"state":"hgh            "},
{"name":"ty","qualification":"gfhgf","login_id":null,"state":"hgh            "},
{"name":"sdg","qualification":"fdgfd","login_id":null,"state":"ghg            "},
{"name":"cbn","qualification":"bvn","login_id":null,"state":"nmbv           "},
{"name":"cbn","qualification":"bvn","login_id":null,"state":"nmbv           "},
{"name":"","qualification":"","login_id":null,"state":"               "},
{"name":"","qualification":"","login_id":null,"state":"               "},
{"name":"gfdgfsd","qualification":"ghfh","login_id":null,"state":"               "},
{"name":"","qualification":"","login_id":null,"state":"               "},
{"name":"","qualification":"","login_id":null,"state":"               "},
{"name":"fhdgh","qualification":"gfdh","login_id":null,"state":"               "},
{"name":"fhdgh","qualification":"gfdh","login_id":null,"state":"               "},
{"name":"sfdfdf","qualification":"","login_id":null,"state":"               "},
{"name":"sfdfdf","qualification":"","login_id":null,"state":"               "},
{"name":"sadada","qualification":"","login_id":null,"state":"               "},
{"name":"sadada","qualification":"","login_id":null,"state":"               "},
{"name":"dsfadfasd","qualification":"","login_id":null,"state":"               "},
{"name":"dsfadfasd","qualification":"","login_id":null,"state":"               "},
{"name":"sadfs","qualification":"dsfdf","login_id":"sdfsgfdg","state":"fgdf           "},
{"name":"sdffg","qualification":"jillu","login_id":"hhhhh","state":"jhkh           "},
{"name":"sdffg","qualification":"jillu","login_id":"hhhhh","state":"jhkh           "},
{"name":"dfdsg","qualification":"dsfgf","login_id":"hhhhj","state":"hhh            "}]
```

This is my controller,

```
public JsonResult JqGrid()  
        {
            var dbResult = db.registers.ToList();
            var registers = (from reg in dbResult
                             select new
                             {
                                reg.name,
                                reg.qualification,
                                reg.login_id,
                                reg.state,

                             });
            return Json(registers, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

This is my view,

```
@model IEnumerable<mvcComplte.Models.register>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "JqGrid";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@section styles
{
<link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/jquery.jqGrid/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.base.css" /> 

}
@section scripts
{

<script src="~/Scripts/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
                url: 'Home/JqGrid',
                datatype: "json",
                colNames: ['name', 'qualification','state', 'login_id'],
                colModel: [
                    { name: 'name', width: 75 },
                    { name: 'qualification', width: 150 },
                    { name: 'state', width: 150 },
                    { name: 'login_id', width: 150 },
                ],
                gridview: true,
                width: 750,
                height: auto,
            });
        });
 </script>
}

<h2>JqGrid</h2>
<table id="list"></table>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Where you have `<table id="list"></table>` on the page? What is `height: auto`? It should be fixed to `height: "auto"`. You should add `loadonce: true`, `autoencode: true` options. I strictly recommend you to include `id` property to every item returned from the server. **Which version of jqGrid you use  and from which fork ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)?** I recommend you to use free jqGrid 4.13.1, the fork which I develop after making Guriddo jqGrid commercial.

Comment: Replace local URLs to jqGrid files to URLs from CDN described in [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs).

Comment: there is table id after the script i didnt post @Oleg sir

Comment: am using jqGrid 4.4.4 version, and its showing grid also its reaching to action method which i mentioned in url,saving the data in json object,but its not binding to grid @Oleg, colud you please tel me..what is the problem

Comment: **Do you tried with URLs of free jqGrid 4.13.1 or not?** You need just  Is it so difficult to change l lines of HTML code and to retry (at last temporary for an experiment)? Using of CDN is much better as usage of local jqGrid if you don't many any customization of HTTP headers of static files. If you do want to use jqGrid loaded from NuGet for example then you should uninstall NuGet package [jQuery.jqGrid/](https://www.nuget.org/packages/jQuery.jqGrid/) and install [free-jqGrid](https://www.nuget.org/packages/free-jqGrid/). jqGrid 4.4.4 is more as 3 years old and it's dead.

Comment: **Do you made the changes which I described in my first comment?** Do you included jQuery **before** jqGrid? The list on included jqGrid files is: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/free-jqgrid/4.13.1/css/ui.jqgrid.min.css">`, `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/free-jqgrid/4.13.1/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.min.js"></script>`, `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/free-jqgrid/4.13.1/js/jquery.jqgrid.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Have `db.registers` a column with id? I strictly recommend you to include it too. I recommend you additionally to open your page in Internet Explorer or in Chrome with started Developer Tools (press F12 to start) and to reload the page with started debugger of Developer Tools. You should post the error message which you will see on the Console.